# Finding probability from different dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, probability

I have a dataframe with the columns Winner, Sex_female and Sex_male. The three columns are filled with integers of 0 and 1. I want to find the probability of the Female winners and the Male winners.

Winner:
0 = not a winner
1 = winner

Sex_female:
0 = not a female
1 = female

Sex_male:
0 = not a male
1 = male

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
def female_survival(dframe):
    female_survived = 0
    for i in dframe:
        if (dframe["Sex_female"] == 1) & (dframe["Survived"] == 1):
            female_survived += 1
        else:
            female_survived += 0
```

This returns an error of
**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Answer (score 0):

You should not loop on a dataframe as you have done above, a better way will be:

```
for i in range(dframe.shape[0]):
        if (dframe.iloc[i]["Sex_female"] == 1) & (dframe.iloc[i]["Survived"] == 1):
            female_survived += 1
        else:
            female_survived += 0
```

You can use also use the `value_counts()` function here instead of loops.

Comment: You shouldn't even loop like that: `numpy.bitwise_and(df['Sex_female'], df['Survived']).sum()`

Comment: Also, that `else` statement is superfluous

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
        #creating a dummy dataframe
        df=pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array([[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]]).transpose(),columns=['Winner','Sex_female','Sex_male'])


        Output:
                Winner  Sex_female  Sex_male
            0   1   1   0
            1   0   1   0
            2   0   0   1
            3   0   0   1
            4   1   0   1
            5   1   1   0
            6   0   1   0
            7   1   0   1
            8   0   1   0
            9   1   1   0

     #Find the number of females who survived and how many did not
     df[df['Sex_female']==1]['Winner'].value_counts() 


    Output:
        1    3
        0    3
```

Instead 
`df[df['Sex_female']==1]['Winner'].mean()` will give the percentage of females who survived